# F#, small type inference / annotation error

Tags: datetime, types, f#, type-inference

This line in F# gives the error that a type annotation may be needed, at "x.Day".

```
  let daysList = List.map (fun x -> x.Day) datesList
```

But intellisense shows that x is of type DateTime (at "fun x"). And that datesList is of type DateTime list. So I'm perplexed as to why I have to declare the type of x like so and then everything works:

```
  let daysList = List.map (fun (x:System.DateTime) -> x.Day) datesList
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The F# compiler generally prefers inferring types from left to right, so if you write it using the pipe operator, it works, assuming that `datesList` is a `DateTime list`:

```
let daysList = datesList |> List.map (fun x -> x.Day)
```

Why, then, can IntelliSense determine that `x` is a `DateTime`? Beats me, but in my experience it's fairly common that IntelliSense sometimes disagrees with the compiler.

BTW, that *left to right* rule doesn't always seem to be strict, either. I often have to experiment a bit before I get everything right.

Comment: Thanks. I may be starting to get the hang of this.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken: The left-to-right ordering is always necessary when accessing a method or property. It is also necessary when accessing a record field _unless_ the record type is in scope (from the same module or an `open`ed module) _and_ no other record type with a field with the same name is defined in-between (type inference will prefer the closest record type).